# What will happen after the Judgement Day?

Tags: non-muslim, belief, day-of-judgement

I am having this doubt which is bothering me a lot.

What will happen after the Judgment Day?

I know people will be given heaven or hell based on their action on earth. But what happens next?

Comment: I think you should split your question into multiple ones: a) What happens after Judgement Day; b) What happens to folks who have never heard of Islam? c) Will all Muslims go to Heaven after they get punished in Hell?

Comment: i see in revisions that 2 questions are deleted by author. one of them is moved to other question, i see in profile of the author: "What happens to people who have never heard of Islam?". @Najeeb 3rd(c) question is "But what is the ultimatum after every people in heaven what happens next?" which means, i think, whether there is anything after paradise, like the author has not heard that it is eternal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the name of Allah the merciful the compassionate

According to the noble Qur'an everyone will encounter death:

> “Wherever you are, death will overtake you, though you are in lofty
> towers.” [**(4:78)**](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/4:78)

After death, souls will enter [barzakh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barzakh) [**[ref]**](http://www.al-islam.org/islamic-thought-book-one-muhammad-saidi-mihr-amir-divani/section-three-philosophical-approaches) and those who enter heaven after barzakh will stay there forever. Almighty Allah says in his noble Qur'an as such:

> “Those who are in awe of the Beneficent God in secret and come with a
> penitent heart: Enter it in peace, that is the day of abiding”
> [**(50:33,34)**](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/50:33)

According to [Mohammad Ali Shomali](http://www.shomali.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1&Itemid=5) in his [Self-knowledge](http://www.al-islam.org/self-knowledge-mohammad-ali-shomali/endless-future):

> Those people who enter hell are of two kinds. Disbelievers who are
> against the truth will stay there forever. But those believers who
> will enter hell for their bad deeds will finally enter heaven after
> they will have been cleansed.
>
> “And (as to) those who disbelieve, their
> guardians are Shaytans who take them out of the light into the
> darkness; they are the inmates of the fire, in it they shall abide.”
> [**(2:257)**](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/2:257)

### Rank of believers in heaven

Believers who enter heaven are not of the same ranks in heaven and based on their action in the world, they are in certain situation in heaven. For example we read in hadith (tradition) from the holy Prophet:

> مَن جَاءَهُ المَوتُ وهُوَ يَطْلُبُ العِلمَ لِيُحيِيَ بهِ الإسْلامَ
> كانَ بَينَهُ وَبَيْنَ الأنْبِياءِ دَرَجَةٌ واحِدَةٌ في الجَنَّةِ.
>
> “Whoever dies while seeking knowledge with the intention of reviving
> Islam, then there is one rank in Heaven between him and the Prophets. [**[ref]**](http://www.al-islam.org/divine-perspective-on-rights-a-commentary-of-imam-sajjads-treatise-of-rights/right-n-19-right#footnote11_dq2jm2q)

This hadith shows the different ranks that believers might have in heaven. Believers may get higher ranks the more they stay in heaven and worship the almighty Allah.

> In it there will be things for which the souls of men yearn and which
> give delight to their eyes, and they shall reside therein forever. It
> is an abode the inmates whereof are the neighbors of Allah, and His
> friends (awliya') and loved ones and the recipients of His generosity.
> And they are of different kinds and ranks. Among them will be some who
> like angels will receive their favors by sanctifying and glorifying
> Allah and declaring His greatness [**[ref]**](http://www.al-islam.org/a-shiite-creed-shaykh-saduq/concerning-garden-al-janna-and-fire-nar).

And the least of believers in point of rank in Paradise shall have ten times of what he had in this world.

Comment: Salam, it might be worth highlighting parts of your answer by editing it. There're a lot of quotes and not much explanation.

Comment: Good answer! But can you add the references please?

Comment: Is there a hadith that the last paragraph is based on?